# Is Pay-Per-Install (like Appbrain) pay only after user install from Play Store?

Tags: android, admob, leadbolt

I was developing some apps. Now i'm thinking to upload on Google Play for free. My app is designed for **offline** use. I'm not clear about that they pay per install after user install my app from anywhere or play store. Is Pay Per Install is best options for my app? How do you think? Pls leave your idea. Is there any Ads service for my need? I have read that Admob is not much for offline app. They business work as a CPC. Do you have any idea about leadbolt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They all require internet connection.

So it sounds like your app is not a good fit for in-app advertising.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just testing admob on my app. I feel that ads are not interesting. Can i customize the ads? eg. I want to show game ads on my app. Can I?

Comment: You can filter the ads that are shown based upon category, but you will be limiting your potential ad revenue. A good ad network will learn which ads are a good fit for your app and only show ads that *are* interesting.